# Custom 'console.log' plugin Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext3

I do a lot of JavaScript projects, and I miss a great feature from PHPStorm. Now I don't understand Python that much. So hope you can help me.

This is what I want:

```
'test'.log => console.log('test');
test.log => console.log(test);
```

So with a single tabtrigger `.log`

I want to retrieve anything before the `.log`. And then I will transform it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a plugin to retrieve the text before `.log` and replace it in the view:

```py
import re

import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class PostSnippetLogCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        for sel in view.sel():
            pos = sel.b
            text_before = view.substr(sublime.Region(view.line(pos).a, pos))

            # match the text before in reversed order
            m = re.match(r"gol\.(\S*)", text_before[::-1])
            if not m:
                continue
            # retrieve the text before .log and reestablish the correct order
            text_content = m.group(1)[::-1]
            # create the replacements text and region
            replace_text = "console.log({});".format(text_content)
            replace_reg = sublime.Region(pos - len(m.group(0)), pos)
            # replace the text
            view.replace(edit, replace_reg, replace_text)
```

Afterwards add this keybinding to trigger the command if it is prefixed with `.log` inside a javascript document.

```js
{
    "keys": ["tab"],
    "command": "post_snippet_log",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operand": "source.js" },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "\\.log$" },
    ],
},
```